# GameCenter Integration with SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, game-center

I'm simply trying to log a high score of a single game mode in a game I'm making. I have a leaderboard setup in Game Center on iTunes Connect.

So, my question is, how do I integrate this into my game? I've seen other solutions but can't seem to figure out how they fit into my project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your view controller implement the `GKGameCenterControllerDelegate`
2. Create a local player

   ```
   var localPlayer: GKLocalPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()
   ```
3. Authenticate the player in the `viewDidLoad` with the game center and present the authentication success

   ```
   localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {(ViewController, error) -> Void in
       if((ViewController) != nil) {
           self.presentViewController(ViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
       }
   }
   ```
4. Report your score from anywhere in your game

   ```
   if (GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated) {
     let gkScore = GKScore(leaderboardIdentifier: "YOUR-LEADERBOARD-ID")
     gkScore.value = Int64(YOUR-SCORE)
     GKScore.reportScores([gkScore], withCompletionHandler: ( { (error: NSError!) -> Void in
           if (error != nil) {
                // handle error
                println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription);
           } else {
                println("Score reported: \(gkScore.value)")
           }
       }))
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. I didn't need to implement the protocol though. All I needed to do was import GameKit.